# Extracting relative risk values from a CARBayes CAR model in R

Tags: r, polygon

I'm working with the CARBayes package in R, modeling disease maps. I have a working convolution prior (BYM) CAR model, `spatial_mod`, which contains fitted values based on my model. My model takes on the form:

```
 O[i] ~ Poisson(mu[i])
log(mu[i]) = log(E[i]) + a[i] + bX1[i]+  b[i] +  h[i]
```

Where `O[i]` are my observed disease counts per region, and `E[i]` are my expected disease counts per region. The `b[i]` and `h[i]` terms are my structured and unstructured random effect terms.

This is the model I run in CARBayes:

```
form<-O~1+offset(log(E))

model_spatial<-S.CARbym(formula=form, data=data,family="poisson", W=W.mat, burnin=10000, n.sample=16000,thin=10)
```

I can extract the fitted values from my model as:

```
model_spatial$fitted.values
```

To find the RR for each region, i, would I simply exponetiate these fitted values?

```
exp(model.spatial$fitted.values)
```

In winBUGS, I know that the RR[i] for a given region will be `exp(a[i] + bX1[i]+  b[i] +  h[i])`

But, I don't know if this is true in CARBayes.

I apologize for not providing reproducible data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use the example from `example(S.CARbym)` as a Poisson model, to get something equivalent to what you are doing:

```
> model <- S.CARbym(
   formula=Y~x1+x2+offset(log(trials)),
   family="poisson", W=W, burnin=100,n.sample=1000)
```

Then `model$fitted.values`, or `fitted(model)` are on the scale of the counts in `Y` (try plotting them against your observed counts), so that tells you they are estimates of Observed case counts. Don't exponentiate them, that's already been done!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already plotted my fitted values. I guess what my question boils down to is finding the area-specific convolution prior values (b[i] and h[i]) from the model in order to calculate the RRs, where RR[i]=exp(a[i] + bX1[i]+  b[i] +  h[i]) as above.

Comment: `fitted(model)` is `mu[i]`, where `log(mu[i]) = log(E[i]) + a[i] + bX1[i]+  b[i] +  h[i]`, so `log(fitted(model)[i]) - log(E[i])` gets the rest (`a[i]+...`) of the model.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks for your help (would upvote but I don't have enough rep on this forum yet).

Comment: I think it would actually be log(fitted(model))/log(E), no?

Comment: `log(mu[i]) = log(E[i]) + ...` is what you wrote and `mu[i]` is `fitted(m)[i]`. You could do `log(mu[i]/E[i])` on the LHS though [because log(a)-log(b) = log(a/b)]